# UISearchDisplayController disable searchbar search key

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using a UISearchDisplayController to display a UISearchBar.  By default  the return key is disabled when the UISearchBar text field is empty.  I tried the following my viewDidLoad:

```
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar subviews]) {

    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {

        [(UITextField*)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES ];

    }
}
```

But, still no luck.  First, i thought by default enablesReturnKeyAutomatically is YES, but it doesn't seem like it.  Second,  I can't seem to set it manually.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but:

```
[(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
```

will cause the return button on the keyboard to be always active.